# go to external site if it's an hyperlink

Tags: asp.net

I have a "view" link to an aspx page in a gridview for each row.

Depending on the type of resource 1)File or 2)Hyperlink , it should either download the file or go to the hyperlink mentioned.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a id="View" href="../resources/ResourceFile.aspx?Id=<%# Eval("Id")%>" target="_blank">View</a>
                </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I got it working for the file type but how do I redirect to an external link like "www.yahoo.com" if it's an hyperlink.

In the code behind

```
if(resource.ResourceType.ToLower().Equals("hyperlink")){
                    // what should i do here?
               // the link is stored in resource.value
                }
```

EDIT : Figured that the link should have an http:// prefix to work. Feeling stupid now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured that the link should have an `http://` prefix to work.

Answer (score 3):

Does the resource object have access to the URL that you wish to redirect to?  If so, you could use Response.Redirect.

```
if(resource.ResourceType.ToLower().Equals("hyperlink")){
   Response.Redirect(resource.Url);
}
```

Comment: Great, then Response.Redirect(resource.value); should do it. :)

Comment: @David. Found that the value should have an http:// prefix. That was why it wasn't working for me earlier.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add an asp.net hyperlink to the item template. Then handle the RowDataBound event to dynamically change the NavigateURL property of the hyperlink. This way you avoid the postpack.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Hyperlink runat="server" id="View" target="_blank">View</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink hl = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("View");
        hl.NavigateUrl = "Link to file or url based on resource type";
    }
}
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx][1]

[1]: MSDN Example

Comment: I use the resourcefile.aspx in a few other places.I put the logic to figure out if it's a file or url in the code behind of that page.
The link is same whether it's a file or an url