# How do I get ASP.NET Hyperlinks to point to different domains?

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect, hyperlink

In asp.net, every link created whether html  tag or asp hyperlink all end up with my domain name in them. If I programmatically create the link www.google.com it ends up as mydomainname.com/www.google.com. Is this an IIS problem? I cant figure out why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

Just add https:// or http:// before your link.

Answer (score 0):

There's another Stack Overflow post about this:

[go to external site if it's an hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315159/go-to-external-site-if-its-an-hyperlink)

You need to prefix the external website you're linking to with "http[s]://".